# Merge timestamp column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a log file that has large number of columns and I would like to merge timestamp columns into one as shown in the example below

```
start time  End time process ID. . . 
10:02       11:10    A       1
10:32       11:23    B       1
...         ....     A       2
...         ....     B       2
...         ....     C       2
```

Note: Single ID can have multiple similar processes e.g. multiple A in an ID

```
time     process   ID . . .
10:02    A_start   1  
11:10    A_end     1
10:32    B_start   1
11:23    B_end     1
....     A_start   2
....     A_end     2
....     B_start   2
....       ...    ..
```

Trying with melt on pandas but it seem I am missing something here

```
df.melt(id_vars=["ID", "process"], 
        var_name="End time", 
        )
```

Comment: Do you always have a single given process per ID? or can you have multiple A/1?

Comment: ID can have single or  multiple processes,

Comment: No I mean multiple **same** process per ID (if yes, please update the example)

Comment: yes as you can see in the example ID 1 has A , B processes and ID 2 also has A, B processes

Comment: still not my question, but doesn't matter, let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72783921/16343464) works for your, if not we'll work from there ;)

Comment: yes this could be possible when ID can have multiple similar processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with a bit of reshaping:

```
out = (df
 .rename(columns={'start time': 'start', 'End time': 'end'})
 .melt(['process', 'ID'], value_name='time')
 .assign(process=lambda d: d['process']+'_'+d.pop('variable'))
)
```

output:

```
   process  ID   time
0  A_start   1  10:02
1  B_start   1  10:32
2    A_end   1  11:10
3    B_end   1  11:23
```

used input:

```
  start time End time process  ID
0      10:02    11:10       A   1
1      10:32    11:23       B   1
```

Comment: I have to add all the column names except time column in `.melt()`, rest it works fine.

Comment: Yes, if you have many, you can use `df.columns.difference` to help you ;)